# How to delete an item in an array while using a Class Template?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, class-template

I'm trying to delete "GoodBye" from the `Remove` function and then print a list with it missing.

I'm getting an error saying:

> Error  1   error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'void*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;

template <class New_Type>
class Array_Class
{
public:
    Array_Class();
    ~Array_Class();
    void Add(New_Type item);
    int Search(New_Type item);
    void Remove(New_Type item);
    void Print();


private:
    New_Type *A;
    New_Type word;
    int count;
};

template <class New_Type>
Array_Class<New_Type>::Array_Class()
{
    cout << "You are inside the default constructor.\n";
    cout << "New_Type has a size of " << sizeof(New_Type) << " bytes\n\n";
    count = 0;
    A = new New_Type[SIZE];
}

template <class New_Type>
Array_Class<New_Type>::~Array_Class()
{
    cout << "The Destructor has been called.\n\n";
    delete[] A;
    count = 0;
    A = 0;
}

template <class New_Type>
void Array_Class<New_Type>::Add(New_Type item)
{
    if (count<SIZE)
    {
        A[count++] = item;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The array is full.\n";
    }
}


template <class New_Type>
int Array_Class<New_Type>::Search(New_Type item)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        if (item == A[i])
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

`item` is Goodbye. `word` will save the copy that gets deleted.

```
template <class New_Type>
void Array_Class<New_Type>::Remove(New_Type item)
{
    int i;
    word = item;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (item == A[i])
        {

            delete A[i];

        }

    }


}

template <class New_Type>
void Array_Class<New_Type>::Print()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout << "A[" << i << "] = " << A[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The main function which will add "GoodBye" and other words to `my_String`.

```
int main()
{
    Array_Class<string> my_String;
    Array_Class<int> my_Ints;
    Array_Class<char> my_Chars;

    my_String.Add("Hello");
    my_String.Add("GoodBye");
    my_String.Add("ComeHere");
    my_String.Add("SayNo");

    my_Chars.Add('a');
    my_Chars.Add('b');
    my_Chars.Add('c');
    my_Chars.Add('d');
    my_Chars.Add('e');
    my_Chars.Add('f');
    my_Chars.Add('g');

    my_String.Print();
    my_Ints.Print();
    my_Chars.Print();

    cout << endl;

    my_String.Search("Hello");
    my_String.Search("SayNo");
```

`my_String.Remove` will remove `GoodBye` from `my_String`:

```
    my_String.Remove("GoodBye");

    my_String.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wrong syntax for deleting?

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector` and have it do all of the hard work?

Comment: I agree, but I can't use vectors because it's a lab designed to teach me class templates.

Comment: So does the lab show you that you need a copy constructor and assignment operator, along with the destructor (also called the `rule of 3`)?  The issue I have with a lot of these courses is that many of them do not tell you the whole story when it comes to creating classes, giving the student a false sense that they are coding "correctly".

Comment: There was no word about the rule of 3, but it did explain about constructors, destructors, states, mutators, etc when the lab was about basic classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Remove` function should not be issuing any calls to `delete`.  What it should be doing is shifting the elements "up" by one and decreasing the `count` member variable.  This in effect "removes" the item from the Array.

To shift the elements up, you write a loop where you replace element `i` with element `i+1`, where you start the loop at the item you want to remove.

Comment: I see what you mean. Something like "count--; A[i++]"? I was able to delete SayNo

Comment: You need to loop to move all of the elements "up".  Where is the loop to move all the items up by 1?  Draw it on paper -- you have an array of 10 items, and you "remove" the 5th element.  To remove element 5, you overwrite it with element 6, you then overwrite  element 6 with element 7, overwrite element 7 with element 8, etc.  Even though the array is fixed in size, this mimics shrinking the array.

Comment: I sort of got it. I made the found element the last element in the array then deleted the count, so it's like it was deleted or switched places.   for (i = 0; i <count; i++)
 {
 
  if (item == A[i])
  {
  A[i] = A[count -1];
  count -= 1;
  }

 }

Answer (score 1):

However your array is dynamically allocated, you can't just call `delete` on particular elements of it. This is a contiguous block of memory. You can do what @PaulMcKenzie said - To find element that matches element passed as an argument to `Remove` function and then shift to the left remaining array elements, then decrease `count` member variable. I solved it, but since this is homework posting it wouldn't be wise. Here's a very weird pseudo-code of mine. I hope you understand that concept.

```
//array elements : Hello, GoodBye, ComeHere, SayNo 
my_String.Remove("GoodBye");
// found index of element to remove = 1;
// decrement count
// loop from saved index through count-1:
//     A[i] = A[i+1];
// There will be two iterations of this loop. here's how array would look like:
// 1st: array elements : Hello, ComeHere, ComeHere, SayNo
// 2nd: array elements : Hello, ComeHere, SayNo, SayNo
```

Then, because of decrementing `count`, last element won't be printed.
And in c++, for dynamic arrays `std::vector` is way to go.